# Show popular post by category code

Tags: categories, query, popular-posts

How do I show popular post by category code

I have add code

```
<?php 
$popularpost  = new WP_Query( array( 
    'cat'=> 2, 
    'posts_per_page' => 1, 
    'meta_key' => 'post_views_count', 
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 
    'order' => 'DESC'  
) ); 
query_posts($popularpost); 
if (have_posts()) : 
    while (have_posts()) : 
        the_post(); ?>
        <li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
        <?php 
    endwhile; 
endif; 
wp_reset_query(); 
?>
```

but my code is not correct.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are running two queries in one. You should only run one, and definitely not with `query_posts`. You should never ever use [`query_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts)

> **Note:** This function isn't meant to be used by plugins or themes. As explained later, there are better, more performant options to alter the main query. query_posts() is overly simplistic and problematic way to modify main query of a page by replacing it with new instance of the query. It is inefficient (re-runs SQL queries) and will outright fail in some circumstances (especially often when dealing with posts pagination).

You should only use [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) or [`get_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) for custom queries. Your query should have the following format

```
<?php 
$popularpost  = new WP_Query( array( 
    'cat'=> 2, 
    'posts_per_page' => 1, 
    'meta_key' => 'post_views_count', 
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 
    'order' => 'DESC'  
) );

if ($popularpost->have_posts()) {
    while ($popularpost->have_posts()) {
        $popularpost->the_post(); ?>
        <li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
        <?php 
    } 
    wp_reset_postdata();
} 
?>
```

Comment: i'm add code to index.php but don't show any thing? how to cheking it's?

Comment: Sorry, had a slight problem there. Corrected my code